# get course total from multiple courses in moodle

Tags: moodle

I am wanting to have a common certificate for multiple courses in moodle. Is there any way to get individual courses total and restrict this certificate resource based on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is no default feature in moodle to do this. But you can create your own custom certificate activity module on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Start your exploration here in the moodle certificate module.  This is a standard plugin that has customize options.  [moodle docs certificate module](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Certificate_module).